# Dynamic VLOOKUP formular

Tags: excel, dynamic, vlookup

I am trying to write a formular in excel which dynamically outputs the value of the timezone in a new column by getting the required data from another spreadsheet with columns stateprovince and location.

I keep getting missing values because my formular is not dynamic. Please how do I rectify this issue ?

I keep getting missing values (N/A) for a few of the rows because my formular is not dynamic. Please how do I rectify this issue ?

Below is my formular as well as a screenshots of my excel sheets

```
=IF('Helptable Currency_Language'!F2="";VLOOKUP('New Entries'!C2;'Helptable Currency_Language'!A:G;7;);VLOOKUP('New Entries'!I2;'Helptable Currency_Language'!F:G;2;))
```

Comment: There is no sample data hence from the formula which you have posted, i can see you are missing the last param of the `VLOOKUP()` function. It needs to be either `FALSE`/`0` which means `exact match`  or `TRUE`/`1` which means an `approximate match`, based on your requirements. **[Read](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)**

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. Nevertheless, this hasn't solved my problem for the two missing values. I still get the N/A error in the cells

Answer (score 0):

What I can guess that you run `VLOOKUP` over "A:G" or "F:G", where the last range is the subrange of the first one. `VLOOKUP` requires the first column of the range to be ordered if the fourth argument is omitted (which means TRUE). Most probable, "A:G" range can be ordered by "A" or by "F" but not by both at same time. If the range is sorted by "A", try to use the next formula:

```
=IF('Helptable Currency_Language'!F2="";VLOOKUP('New Entries'!C2;'Helptable Currency_Language'!A:G;7;);VLOOKUP('New Entries'!I2;SORT('Helptable Currency_Language'!F:G);2;))
```

If exact match is required (which is expected based on the provided task description), add `FALSE` as the fourth argument to `VLOOKUP`:

```
=IF('Helptable Currency_Language'!F2="";VLOOKUP('New Entries'!C2;'Helptable Currency_Language'!A:G;7;FLASE);VLOOKUP('New Entries'!I2;'Helptable Currency_Language'!F:G;2;FLASE))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. You are right, I am looking for an exact match for the missing cells. This solution gives me the exact same results that I have been getting with my formular. They cant seem to find the data from the other sheet for the two cells.
P:S: I have verified and the values for the cells are not missing, so it is a logic issue not a data one

Comment: You need to check your data for extra spaces, similar looking letters etc. Can you provide a data sample?

Comment: For the sample data,apparently I am not yet eligible to post images ;) I have an idea what the problem is. At the beginning of my formular i encoded that when the F2 is blank, it should fulfill the rest of the conditions. Hence it is giving me results for only cells where the F2 is blank :) 
=IF('Helptable Currency_Language'!F2="";VLOOKUP('New Entries'!C2;'Helptable Currency_Language'!A:G;7;);VLOOKUP('New Entries'!I2;'Helptable Currency_Language'!F:G;2;)) I need to modify my logic so that it shows results for both when F2 is blank as well as when it isnt blank. That is my current quagmire :)